# DataContractJsonSerializer exception

Tags: c#, json, jquery, exception, ashx

I am getting this error when using my class.

## Error

> Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None' with
>   name '', namespace

## My Class

```cs
[DataContract]
public class EntryData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string EntryId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string TotalVoteCount { get; set; }

    public static T Deserialise<T>(string json)
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
            obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream); // getting exception here                    
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

## USAGE

```cs
string responseJson = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
var results = EntryData.Deserialise<EntryData>(response)
```

I have seen online that it has to do with the `memoryStream position` BUT as you can see i am setting it to the beginning.

Please help.

## Json going to handler

I don't set StatusCode or TotalVoteCount when passing JSON in. I don't think this is the problem though.

```
{
    "EntryId":"43",
    "EmailAddress":"test@email.com"
}
```

## ANSWER

Instead of using Deserialize method in my class I am using now this.

```cs
//commented out this code.        
string responseJson = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
var results = EntryData.Deserialise<EntryData>(response)

// this is the way to go using JavaScriptSerializer   
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var results = serializer.Deserialize<EntryData>(response);
```

Comment: Could you post your JSON? I think this might be caused by your JSON names don't match your C# class and property names. This would cause the serializer to not know how to translate between the two.

Comment: see my json request in question please

Comment: Thanks, hmmm... I'm out of ideas then. I agree with you that leaving off those fields shouldn't be causing the problem. By default the DataMember's IsRequired property is false so I think it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be caused by your JSON names not matching your property names in C#?

My understanding is that

```
{
     "FirstName" : "Mark"
}
```

Would be able to deserialize into:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person 
{    
     [DataMember]
     public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

but this wouldn't be able to serialize

```
{
     "Name" : "Mark"
}
```

unless you changed your C# class to have an explicit name for the DataMember

```
[DataContract]
public class Person 
{    
     [DataMember(Name="Name")]
     public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

I'm not sure which error this would cause though. I Don't have enough first hand experience.

Comment: see my json request in question please

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it could be an encoding problem? Have you tried using [Encoding.UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) instead of Unicode?

All the examples I have seen using DataContractSerializer have used a UTF-8 encoding.

[Encoding.Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx) is a UTF-16 encoding.

I can't find any documentation explicitly stating which encodings DataContractSerializer supports. I assume it would be smart enough to detect the proper encoding, but I don't know a whole whole lot about encodings. Maybe that isn't really possible in this instance.

Comment: I don't think it is a Encoding issue. anyways found a solution.. please see my answer